# Issue with file_get_contents restricted

Tags: php

Currently I am getting a 403 forbidden error with my code.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://website.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in simple_html_dom.php on line 75
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in file.php on line 20
```

Here's the code that I am using (the `simple_html_dom.php` portion is just the library of simple_html_dom.

```
$html = file_get_html("https://website.com");   
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{
  // the foreach data here.
}
```

The `foreach` is where the error is happening, the same exact code was working previously, and then randomly stopped. I assume one of two things happened, Cloudflare blocked my websites IP, or I reached my quota for amount of requests.

How can I bypass this using Proxies, or even Curl?

Comment: You ask the website operator if they have an api you can use instead of scraping their site hard enough to get blocked.

Comment: @Sammitch I don't entirely agree with how you worded it, but you're not wrong.

Comment: @JohnDoe trying to fend off scrapers who think they're entitled to my data has unfortunately consumed far too much of my professional life. It's a wonder that I managed to get that comment off without even a single profanity.